# Change photos to watercolor paintings

Tags: algorithm, graphics

I'm now trying to find an algorithm that can make the photographs to watercolor-like paintings. The [Waterlogue](http://www.waterlogueapp.com/) app makes it very well. So I'm wondering which algorithm they used.

Comment: Looks like brush sized dot approximation of the image with finite palette of colors + some filtering. See how [color dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) is made it is similar process I think. But that is my first look opinion you need to start coding and the trial&error will lead you to solution. Or contact the authors of that App and ask them how they did it.

Comment: thanks! I also think that it really need to do with color dithering and color quantization, I'm now try to code that out.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to simulate the following effects:

- paper texture
- turbulent flow, meaning, how the pigments get moved around
- edge darkening, meaning, pigments get deposited more on edges
- pigment dispersion, meaning, wet-on-wet pigment movement (that's the toughest one)

It's relatively easy to do if you use darkening/lightening function that can work off the current rendered image and a grayscale image that's supposed to simulate one watercolor effect. Read up on Bousseau's work as he kind of pioneered this methodology (except the wet-on-wet).

You can use already made software to turn photograph into watercolor if you are on windows 64 bit. It's called "The Watercolorist" and it's available here (free software): http://3dstereophoto.blogspot.com/p/painting-software.html

The methodology behind "The Watercolorist" is explained in detail. I wrote the software and the links I have provided are to my blog which primarily deals with 3d photography (depth maps, photogrammetry, etc).